# What does the @ symbol mean before a file path in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, at

I've noticed that powershell.exe started csc.exe with a command line like this:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\TEMP\pn1kld2d.cmdline"
```

I've read the [CSC manual page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe), but didn't found any clues about what that @ sign does here.

Does anyone know the purpose of this @ sign?

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure it takes additional arguments from the listed file, but I can't find any reference to back me up.

Comment: That's strange, I've seen some Ursnif/Gozi malware samples perform this activity utilizing malicious VBS files. parentname: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
value: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
cmdline: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\iuy52nsm.cmdline"
cmdline: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\x0mmbazr.cmdline"
cmdline: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /f

Comment: @Baber, this is explainable because this is (unfortunately!) a common behavior of legit Microsoft products - without ANY opportunity for IT Security team to understand what is actually happening on that machine. So as a security guy, you're always blinded here :( Only a proper EDR solution might help - to some extent, of course... No wonder that malicious actors try to hide in the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubts, try inbuilt help `csc.exe /help`:

```
==> pushd "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

==> csc.exe /? | findstr /I "noconfig fullpaths C# @ (R) help"
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.2556.0 for C# 5
This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only
 supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version.
 For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
                        Visual C# Compiler Options
@<file>                        Read response file for more options
/help                          Display this usage message (Short form: /?)
/noconfig                      Do not auto include CSC.RSP file
/fullpaths                     Compiler generates fully qualified paths

==>
```

Then, find [*csc.exe response file* documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option):

> ### @ (C# Compiler Options)
>
> The `@` option lets you specify a file that contains compiler options
>   and source code files to compile.
>
> **Syntax**: `@response_file`
>
> **Arguments**: `response_file` A file that lists compiler options or source code files to compile.
>
> **Remarks**: The compiler options and source code files will be processed by the compiler just as if they had been specified on the
>   command line. 
> ...